# How to add custom method in a java code for event listener code in jbpm

Tags: java, logging, addeventlistener, jbpm

i have implemented custom event listeners for jbpm and used java.util.logging for logging in a separate folder and store there
I want to add a custom public void method and add a logging functions inside its body to place a title in the log file before the lof is displayed
I tried adding the method but jbpm is not recognizing it please guys need help.

Here's my code:

```
public class CustomProcessEventListener implements ProcessEventListener  {
static FileHandler fileTxt;
static SimpleFormatter formatterTxt;
static Logger logger;
static File myObj;
static File myObj2;
public  void befStart() {
```

//NEED TO ADD LOGGER HERE THIS IS THE METHOD I WANT TO ADD

```
}

@Override
public void beforeProcessStarted(ProcessStartedEvent event) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd HHmm");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    WorkflowProcessInstance process = (WorkflowProcessInstance) event.getProcessInstance();
```

Comment: what exactly did you try, how did you try to use it, and what do you mean with "is not recognizing it"?
You mean to say you want to execute certain code before that logging is executed?

Comment: i used custom event listeners and i need to add a custom method inside the code which jbpm is ignoring that method

Comment: need to add a method so that i can add a customised log file on top before the log displays

Comment: yes, so you said, but you're pretty vague. Again, what do you mean by all of that? Can you be more specific/add more information in your question?

Comment: -In eclipse i implemented some custom event listeners to get logs
-i build it using maven and uploaded the jar in kiewb
-in system logs i can now view the logs which is great
-Now i want to add a title on top of the log its process name sort of things
-when i add a method in the code jbpm ignores and runs only listener methods